# fitsSystemWindows does not work in added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androiddesignsupport

In my app I have an activity. The theme for this activity is normal pre-L but is overriden for L and above, with:

```
...
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusTrans</item>
...
```

This activity has a layout like this (`fsw` means that node fitsSystemWindows) to give the Material effect.

```
CoordinatorLayout (fsw)
  L AppBarLayout (fsw)
      L CollapsingToolbarLayout (fsw)
          L ImageView (fsw)
          L Toolbar
      L TabLayout
  L ViewPager
  L FAB
```

Thing is, I add a fullscreen `DialogFragment` via a transaction to this activity, by adding it to android.R.id.content having this layout

```
CoordinatorLayout (fsw)
  L AppBarLayout (fsw)
      L CollapsingToolbarLayout (fsw)
          L FrameLayout
          L Toolbar
      L TabLayout
  L NestedScrollView
```

The initial layout draws the statusBar and then the `Toolbar` below it as expected (ie insets are applied), but the added fragment layout draws the `Toolbar` directly under the statusBar and I cannot seem to get it to draw right.

I dont know what I'm doing wrong. Heres two screen shots showing the problem.

[image: One] [image: Two]

.

**ALSO (BONUS QUESTION!)**

In the same Activity, I set the `Viewpager` to have a ScrollingViewBehavior. 
The fragments that populate the `Viewpager` however have a `ViewFlipper` which switches out one of these: a loadingView(`ProgressBar`), contentView(`RecyclerView`) and emptyView(`LinearLayout`).
This ensures that if theres content, the activity has the desired scrolling effect.

Problem arises with the emptyView because it doesnt center correctly. I've attached an image.

How can I correct (or hack) this behavior?

[image: Three]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the solution? I have exactly the same problem right now :(

Answer (score 2):

Wherever  your replacing your fragment make sure its in a coordinator layout.  For example, if your xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

then wrap that in a coordinatorlayout to resolve the problem.